# How to get the base64 image using xepOnline

Tags: angular, pdf, tobase64string, xeponline

xepOnline.Formatter.Format('content', { render: 'download' }, { embedLocalImages: 'true' });

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested.

Comment: Using this I can able to download the pdf, but i want get the PDF string data or base64 data to attach in email. i have checked in http://www.cloudformatter.com/CSS2Pdf.APIDoc.Usage. kindly help to identify. thanks in advance